# What's the difference between @mui/material and @mui/system?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I'm using `MUIv5` and looking at this [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/understand-mui-packages/), it's still unclear the difference between `@mui/material` vs `@mui/system`.

This is mainly in the context of using the `styled`([link](https://mui.com/system/styled/)) utility.

I've noticed they use both (interchangeably):

`import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';`

`import { styled } from '@mui/system';`

What's the difference/in what context should I use each of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@mui/system` contains all the css values and the `sx` prop.
The `@mui/material` is the thing you usually want to use.
It's hard to differentiate between these two because the `Material UI` uses the `MUI System` among `Joy UI` and `MUI Base` in itself for it's basic css utilities. so when you import material, you are using them both.

You can see the *@mui/system* dependency in the `package.json` file of `@mui/material`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.17.2",
    "@mui/base": "5.0.0-alpha.87",
    "@mui/system": "^5.8.6",
    "@mui/types": "^7.1.4",
    "@mui/utils": "^5.8.6",
    "@types/react-transition-group": "^4.4.4",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "csstype": "^3.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react-is": "^17.0.2",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.2"
  }
```

And also studying the `README.md` file of @mui/material can be helpful for learning more about each package:

```
<h1 align="center">MUI Core</h1>

**MUI Core** contains foundational React UI component libraries for shipping new features faster.

- [_Material UI_](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/overview/) is a comprehensive library of components that features our implementation of Google's [Material Design](https://material.io/design/introduction/) system.

- [_Joy UI_](https://mui.com/joy-ui/getting-started/overview/) is a beautifully designed library of React UI components.

- [_MUI Base_](https://mui.com/base/getting-started/overview/) is our library of "unstyled" components and low-level hooks. With Base, you gain complete control over your app's CSS and accessibility features.

- [_MUI System_](https://mui.com/system/basics/) is a collection of CSS utilities to help you rapidly lay out custom designs.
```